# LaTeX: Problem with the babel package in beamer class with TeXmaker

Tags: latex, babeljs, beamer, texmaker

here is minimal example of my problem:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169,German,handout]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

This compiles on overleaf fine, but on my Windows Workstation with TeXMaker, I get the following error:

**Missing numer, treated as zero \l@German \ldf@fginish \CurrentOption**

It compiles only if I remove the \usepackage{babel} line.

What can I do?

thx

The log file says: (removed because its too large)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
\documentclass[14pt,aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}
```